# what does "Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist" error mean when using cert manager to add ssl to my domain in k8s

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, cert-manager

I tried setting ssl to my domain with cert manager in k8s.

**Firstly, I created 2 services and applied the ingress, so that I can access my service with http request.**

**Then I installed cert-manager with yml file**

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/latest/download/cert-manager.yaml
```

**After that, I set up the issuer and certificate**

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: default
spec:
  acme:
    # Staging API
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: xxx@xxx.xxx
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
    - selector: {}
      http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx

---

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: miniapi-staging
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: miniapi-staging-certificate
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
  commonName: xx1.xx.xxx
  dnsNames:
  - xx1.xx.xxx
  - xx2.xx.xxx
```

**I described Certificate, it showed me**

> Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist

**Then I described challenge, it showed me some pending error**

> Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request 'http://xxx.xxx.xx/.well-known/acme-challenge/AsGBYEbUD8VRYoJsXQQu5b0ntGSS5quq2M7kRx0sFZs': Get "http://xx.xxx.xx/.well-known/acme-challenge/AsGBYEbUD8VRYoJsXQQu5b0ntGSS5quq2M7kRx0sFZs": EOF

**And I checked the url above is valid**, it showed me one ong line string(I have modified the real urls).

I tried so many times but it's the same error, so what am I doing wrong, hope some one could save me from this.

BTW k8s is so hard to learn, how do you guys learn it

Comment: That should work, tested on GCP cluster exactly the same steps. There's potentially the issue with loadbalancer, check [this - related to DO](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2781) and some details [here](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/http01/externalloadbalancer/#load-balancer-http-endpoints).

Comment: Did you manage to move it forward?

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this error message, I followed the [certificate lifecycle flow](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/certificate).

To sum it up, the resources that we are interested are the `certificate`, `certificaterequest`, `order` and `challenge`. I used `kubectl get` and `kubectl describe` to understand the status of these resources.

I started deleting resources that were already created, which should be immediately recreated after deletion. Given that the flow is:

`certificate` -> `certificaterequest` -> `order` -> `challenge`

I started deleting and observing the effect from the end of the flow, hence following the opposite flow order: `challenge`, then `order`, then `certificaterequest` and finally the `certificate`. This didn't work, but after carefully looking at all the resources again, I noticed that deleting the `challenge` had failed. And because of that, a second challenge that had been created was not being processed. This happened most likely because the first challenge was manually deleted from the DNS Zone while it was still being processed.

In order to address this, it is necessary to delete the first challenge. In [this GitHub answer](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/1582#issuecomment-1275941176) you can see how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

That message means that cert-manager can see that you have requested a Certificate and it doesn't have one already so it needs to create (issue) one for you.

As for why the issuance is stuck on the self-check, confirm that retrieving that URL works from inside the cluster, as well as from outside.

Comment: I have checked the url works in browser, how can I confirm that it works ok from inside, I am new to k8s, could you show me how to do this plz.

Comment: @JohnWu Easiest way is to create a pod with `curlimages/curl` image and check your URL like `kubectl exec -it curl-pod -- curl -I www.google.com`